# Haskell Servant POST FormUrlEncoded for (Vector String) field

Tags: postgresql, rest, haskell, servant, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have a data type

```
data Reading = Reading
  { title :: String
  , authors :: Vector String
  , startDate :: Day
  , endDate :: Maybe Day
  }
  deriving (Eq, Show, Generic, FromRow, ...)
```

and I want to be able to create at a POST endpoint for a form

```
    :<|> "reading" :> ReqBody '[FormUrlEncoded] Reading :> Post '[HTML] Reading
```

To do this, I need to derive a `FromForm` instance for `Reading`.  The issue is that there is no instance `FromHttpApiData (Vector String)`.  There does seem to be an instance for `[String]`.  I chose `Vector String` so that I could also derive `FromRow`, which allows me to naturally pull records using postgresql-simple.

So, is there a type that I can use for the `authors` field to derive both `FromRow` and `FromForm`?  I did spend a fair amount of time in the docs and experimenting to no avail.  Or maybe I should be looking a defining a custom instance, or parameterizing the type of `authors` based on the use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does indeed look like there isn't machinery for deriving the `FromForm` instance for `Vector`.

I would define the instance by hand:

```hs
instance FromForm Reading where
  fromForm f =
    Reading
      <$> parseUnique "title" f
      <*> (fromList <$> parseAll "authors" f)
      <*> parseUnique "startDate" f
      <*> parseMaybe "endDate" f
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go.  Will give it a shot tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: Works nicely.  But is it not possible to define `FromHttpApiData (Vector String)`?  Would be a little nicer to have that for all forms.

Comment: Not directly. If you look at [the definition of `FromHttpApiData`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-api-data-0.6/docs/Web-HttpApiData.html#t:FromHttpApiData) you can see that it doesn't provide an instance for list either. Instead, there is a `Generic` instance for `FromForm` and a `GFromForm` instance of the type `(Selector s, FromHttpApiData c) => GFromForm (t :: k) (M1 S s (K1 i [c] :: Type -> Type))`. That's what creates the instance for list. You could probably make your own instance for `Vector` by modifying it but I would just define the `FromRow` instance manually as we did. :)

Comment: Thanks!  That did confuse me, I couldn't find an instance for string but it seemed to work, makes sense now.